# how to make duplicate rows appear in mysql query results node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, duplicates

I am working on a card game to use on Discord that allows up to 3 copies of any one card to be used. I can add the first copy of a card to my mysql database and get the result without a problem, but as soon as I add another copy of a card that already exists in the deck, those copies do not appear in row results when the results from the first query are queried in a second query.

```
var sql1 = `SELECT * FROM deck_cards WHERE deckid = '${deckid}'`;
con.query(sql1, function (err, rows, fields) {
    console.log(rows)
    if (!err) {
        var count = rows.length;

        if (count) {

            var arr_cardid = rows.map(i => i.cardid);

            var sql2 = `SELECT cardname FROM card_info WHERE cardid in ('${arr_cardid.join("','")}') `;
            console.log(sql2)
            con.query(sql2, function (err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    var count = rows.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        arr_cardname = []
                        arr_cardname.push(rows[i].cardname)
                        // list = arr_cardname.join(", ")
                        console.log(arr_cardname)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Table in mysql: https://i.gyazo.com/fb165c1f402f5234a3501e09d715b965.png

Deckid 1 is the deck I query for in the first query. Notice cardid 2 should have 3 total copies of it in the deck. So, I should see 3 copies of cardid 2 when I display the list of cards in that deck. The copies are put into the second query (https://i.gyazo.com/8b6c8426daee2611766242961883ec37.png) However, I only see 1 result for those copies in the output (list), the first one found in row 3 (index 2) of the table. The other 2 copies added at the very end of the table do not appear from the second query results. Is there a way to make the duplicate rows appear in the results of the second query? I have seen union, inner joins, count and such that would be used for a workaround, but I figured I'd ask if there is a simpler and more efficient way to make this work.

Is this an issue with the for loop or the second .join(", ") maybe?

Comment: Maybe try `arr_cardname.push(rows[i].cardname)`.

Comment: @TGrif If you mean to change the list variable to list = arr_cardname.push(rows[i].cardname)? It all of a sudden says I have 12 cards in deck, when I should only have 8. The cards that are copies are also listed as undefined too.

Comment: No I mean declare `arr_cardname` as an empty array then push each card you need into it.

Comment: @TGrif I edited my above code with what I think you mean. Here is what goes in as sql2 and what comes out. Each card looks to be its own array now; duplicates still being ignored. https://i.gyazo.com/85ab4287f76687124c5ab3662f7aff47.png Those are the card names. There should be 2 additional copies of "Aquos Shield" in that list to round out the 8 cards total.